# Rails: Facebook Connect: Client Side/Server Side or Both?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am doing Facebook integration to authenticate users and with my Ruby on Rails application. I've been going through tutorials available online and some SO posts.

I've come across some ways to do this, and most of them talk about what is explained in this post from last year. http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast

My questions are:

1. Can I do with just client side integration?
2. Why do I need server side integration?
3. What are the pros and cons of choosing one?
4. What are the benefits of doing both?
5. What is the best way to do Server side integration (which gem/gems)?

Comment: `My questions are: ` :O

Comment: derekyau understodo and answered the question perfectly. His answer could be beneficial for others. Could you remove the negative vote?

Comment: I didn't gave any -ve vote!

Comment: Glad you got value from the answer :), could you mark it as "accepted"?

Comment: @Shadowfax it seems the question was "put on hold" as too broad, I think Karan has got enough value from this, could we re-open the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do with just client side integration?

- By Client side integration I'm assuming you are referencing simply using FB javascript widgets like the facebook like button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). You can definitely do this, and it will not require your users to "authenticate" to your app at all (ie. go through the oAuth process of giving your app permission etc.) Instead, it will simply pop them to the facebook login page and post directly on their wall/like etc.

> Why do I need server side integration?

- As a continuation to the answer to the first question, sometimes you may want actually want the user to go through the oAuth process so that you can do other things server side. This may include (depending on what permissions you ask for) getting information like an email/picture, country/etc. of your user. Or perhaps it has to do with implementing a particular feature such as for example pulling friends of friends and seeing who is currently using your app.

> What are the pros and cons of choosing one?

- Both are acceptable ways of integration with FB, but using the JS widgets isn't really a login integration, its simply a redirection to FB for them to perform some action. If you really want to enable someone to "sign in with facebook" on your site, you will have to use server side integration (ie. oAuth)
- This in turn means that after the oAuth process, you will have an "authentication" (ie. a token) that represents the user from FB tied to the actual "user" object in your server side database.
- This is useful for many reasons, as outlined above. If you do not need to do complex things, but just want someone to be able to "Like" something, or "Share to wall" you may not need server side integration, but again as mentioned - if you do need "sign in with facebook" at all, it is definitely oAuth and will require the server side integration.

> What are the benefits of doing both?

- Lots to say here... but pretty much see above for answer, can go in to more detail if you have more specific questions.

> What is the best way to do Server side integration (which gem/gems)?

- It would depend upon which gem you are using for your authentication. Personally, I've had great success with the Devise Gem and its built in support for the Omniauth Gem. You can read more about that integration here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: As an added bonus, omniauth allows you to integrate with much more than just FB - take a look at the current strategies it supports here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague. If what you mean by integration is **authentication** then the answer is the only difference is that the client side version needs javascript to work, whereas the server side version doesn't(and implementation is slightly different).

The best way, in my opinion, to do any kind of facebook work in Rails is [the Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)(which uses Omniauth). It's really well documented and it makes navigating the terrible FB API almost bearable.

Again, if what you asked about is authentication then there is no difference. With Koala/Omniauth you can extract user info from the cookie produced with the JS SDK, just as well as you do by using the server-side redirect based login.